# Modify XML existing content in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode, xmltextwriter

Purpose: I plan to Create a XML file with XmlTextWriter and Modify/Update some Existing Content with XmlNode SelectSingleNode(), node.ChildNode[?].InnerText = someting, etc.

After I created the XML file with XmlTextWriter as below.

```
XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter("D:\\learning\\cs\\myTest.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

I practiced the code below. But failed to save my XML file.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("D:\\learning\\cs\\myTest.xml");

XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode myNode;

myNode= root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::books");
```

....

```
textWriter.Close();

doc.Save("D:\\learning\\cs\\myTest.xml");
```

I found it is not good to produce like my way. 
Is there any suggestion about it? 
I am not clear about the concepts and usage of both XmlTextWriter and XmlNode in the same project.
Thank you for reading and replies.

Comment: What node are you trying to retrieve? Could you post some of the xml you are using? I am not aware of descendant::books xpath syntax. Also you don't need the XmlTextWriter, just the XmlDocument

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Well, If you want to update a node in XML, the `XmlDocument` is fine - you needn't use `XmlTextWriter`.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("D:\\build.xml");
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode myNode = root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::books");
myNode.Value = "blabla";
doc.Save("D:\\build.xml");
```

Answer (score 27):

Using LINQ to xml if you are using framework 3.5

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load("books.xml"); 
var query = from c in xmlFile.Elements("catalog").Elements("book")    
            select c; 
foreach (XElement book in query) 
{
    book.Attribute("attr1").Value = "MyNewValue";
}
xmlFile.Save("books.xml");
```

Answer (score 9):

### Forming a XML file

```
XmlTextWriter xmlw = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\WINDOWS\Temp\exm.xml",System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
xmlw.WriteStartDocument();            
xmlw.WriteStartElement("examtimes");
xmlw.WriteStartElement("Starttime");
xmlw.WriteString(DateTime.Now.AddHours(0).ToString());
xmlw.WriteEndElement();
xmlw.WriteStartElement("Changetime");
xmlw.WriteString(DateTime.Now.AddHours(0).ToString());
xmlw.WriteEndElement();
xmlw.WriteStartElement("Endtime");
xmlw.WriteString(DateTime.Now.AddHours(1).ToString());
xmlw.WriteEndElement();
xmlw.WriteEndElement();
xmlw.WriteEndDocument();  
xmlw.Close();
```

### To edit the Xml nodes use the below code

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
doc.Load(@"C:\WINDOWS\Temp\exm.xml"); 
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement["Starttime"]; 
root.FirstChild.InnerText = "First"; 
XmlNode root1 = doc.DocumentElement["Changetime"]; 
root1.FirstChild.InnerText = "Second"; 
doc.Save(@"C:\WINDOWS\Temp\exm.xml");
```

Try this. It's C# code.

Answer (score 6):

The XmlTextWriter is usually used for generating (not updating) XML content. When you load the xml file into an XmlDocument, you don't need a separate writer.

Just update the node you have selected and .Save() that XmlDocument.