# Modify existing Element in XMLfile

Tags: c#, linq

I got an existing XML file

```
 <Customer>
  <PrivateCustomer>
    <Adresse>USA</Adresse>
    <Phone>12345678</Phone>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>20</Age>
    <Sex>Man</Sex>
    <Contract> <Contract/>
  </PrivateCustomer>
  <PrivateCustomer>
    <Adresse>Canada</Adresse>
    <Phone>12345678</Phone>
    <Name>Peter</Name>
    <Age>20</Age>
    <Sex>Woman</Sex>
    <Contract> <Contract/>
  </PrivateCustomer>
 <Customer>
```

In my C# GUI i can select the Names from the xml file in a ComboBox.
I want to modify my XML file, where i can change the content of the "Contract" Element where the Name Element = "John".

Ex.

```
<Customer>
      <PrivateCustomer>
        <Adresse>USA</Adresse>
        <Phone>12345678</Phone>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <Age>20</Age>
        <Sex>Man</Sex>
        <Contract>Sold<Contract/>
      </PrivateCustomer>
      <PrivateCustomer>
        <Adresse>Canada</Adresse>
        <Phone>12345678</Phone>
        <Name>Peter</Name>
        <Age>20</Age>
        <Sex>Woman</Sex>
        <Contract> <Contract/>
      </PrivateCustomer>
     <Customer>
```

How can i do it?

Comment: XDocument is a great place to start. It realy easy to manipulate your dom with linq statements. Have a look at the ReplaceWith functionality, it allows you to replace a node or XElement with a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify an existing element first get the selected name, for example in `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `ComboBox` the use `LINQ to XML:`

```
var selectedName = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("path");
var cust = xDoc.Descendants("PrivateCustomer")
           .FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Element("Name") == selectedName);

if(cust != null)
{
   // edit Customer
   cust.Element("Contract").Value = "some value..";
}
xDoc.Save("path");  // save the xml file
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to do what the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks bro, you are simply Awesome :D

Answer (score 1):

Try [Modify XML existing content in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551307/modify-xml-existing-content-in-c-sharp), the accepted answer has an example where you can search for an element and alter it's value.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("D:\\build.xml");
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode myNode = root.SelectSingleNode("descendant::books");
myNode.Value = "blabla";
doc.Save("D:\\build.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks Robert for expanding on my answer