# Change xml field value depending on values from list

Tags: xml

I have an XML file with several fields.
One of the fields is a reference number (unique).
Another field is a profile-id (not unique), which is always the same for all listings.

Separately, I have a list of reference numbers and their profile-ids (in an excel file).
What I want to do is automatically match the reference  number field, and change the profile-id field in the xml according to the list, so that the resulting xml will have a correct listing of the reference numbers and their respective profile-ids from the list instead of the general, same profile they have now.

Is this possible?

In the example below: the z303-profile-id field is the same for both patrons, each has a unique identifier in z303-ref, and the former is changed according to the latter in the list.

Thank you.

Example:

```
<patron-record>
    <z303>
      <z303-ref>000018804</z303-ref>
      <z303-profile-id>USE_MSL</z303-profile-id>
    </z303>
</patron-record>
<patron-record>
    <z303>
      <z303-ref>000018867</z303-ref>
      <z303-profile-id>USE_MSL</z303-profile-id>
    </z303>
</patron-record>
```

List:

```
000018804               full staff
000018867               Tester
```

Result:

```
<patron-record>
    <z303>
      <z303-ref>000018804</z303-ref>
      <z303-profile-id>full staff</z303-profile-id>
    </z303>
</patron-record>
<patron-record>
    <z303>
      <z303-ref>000018867</z303-ref>
      <z303-profile-id>Tester</z303-profile-id>
    </z303>
</patron-record>
```

Comment: What programming language do you want to use?

Comment: Whichever language can get it done in the easiest way.
I only know jquery, C# and things like HTML5 and CSS, so I'll have to learn how to do this from scratch.

Comment: Can you remove irrelevant elements and instead show how records are repeated?

Comment: Done.
Also I know SQL if that's helpful.

Comment: Half done. I still don't understand on what level the records are repeated, i.e. please use the list of 2 refs, please.

Comment: Is this better? :D
Thank you :D

Comment: Of course it is possible.  What research/effort have you done?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551307/modify-xml-existing-content-in-c-sharp

Comment: I've done some research, but I didn't understand from other threads (including the one you posted) how to do it.
I was sure it is possible, just not how.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can do it in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), a tool I happen to maintain:

```
perl {
    open my $LST, '<', shift or die $!;
    while (<$LST>) {
        chomp;
        my ($ref, $id) = split ' ', $_, 2;
        $profile_id->{$ref} = $id;
    }
} ;
open { shift };
for //patron-record/z303 {
    my $new_id = xsh:lookup('profile_id', z303-ref) ;
    if $new_id set z303-profile-id $new_id ;
}
save :b ;
```

Call as

```
xsh -al script.xsh file.lst file.xml
```

Had you specified the list in an XML file, too, the code would have been much simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately the list is given to me from an outside source, but it might be possible to transform it.
I will check :)
Is that a code for a batch file that I need to run?
Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: It's a `xsh` script you can run, and the next block shows how to run it from the command line or a script.

Comment: No, it's a text file you can get if you copy the contents of the xls file. Handling of XLS files is possible, but very complex.

Comment: So I just copy-paste the xsl into a txt file and change it into an lst file?

Comment: The `:b` option to `save` keeps a backup, so if something goes wrong, you can always restore the original XML :-)

Comment: I'm having trouble installing your tool as per the instructions in your site.
I've unzipped the folder, opened the command line, navigated to it and tried to install via "cpanm XML::XSH2" but received an error message that cpanm is not recognized.

Any advice?

Comment: Try with `cpan` instead of `cpanm`.

Comment: Still saying it is not recognized :(
Do I need to place the downloaded folder in a specific path for it to work?

Comment: @NimrodYanai: What OS are you running?

Comment: Ah, I see. You need to install Perl first. I'd recommend [Strawberry](http://strawberryperl.com/).

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this with an XSL style sheet? D:
This is getting a little complicated for a work computer (they frown on installing things like this, especially since I need a solution that will work for other workers as well)

Comment: There probably is. I don't use XSL when I can avoid it.