# How to read a value from property file and replace it on xml using shell script

Tags: regex, xml, shell, property-files

I have a xml file which contains some `path` at multiple places.

Now I want to fetch value from a `.properties` file mentioned and replace part of `path` where ever it is present in xml.

Like,let's consider I have a xml file as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
...
...
<classpath>

      <pathelement location="/profiles/sh/finalFolder/Apache/example.jar" />

</classpath>

<property name="executable" value="/profiles/sh/finalFolder/Apache/instjamr/install" />

<fileset dir="/profiles/sh/finalFolder/Apache/ant"/>
```

this xml file conatins path `/profiles/sh/finalFolder` with some suffix at  many places.

Now, I have a `path.properties` file which contains (key,value) pairs such as

`FinalFolder=/new/final/exit` (user can edit value anytime in property file)

I want to replace the `path` with the value mentioned in `.properties` file for the key **FinalFolder**.

so now finally, I need to write a code in `.sh` file to do the job.
Please help,Thanks in advance.

(please don't mark this question as duplicate as I din't find a approriate/implementable answer for my question)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42362500/1030675

Comment: @choroba thanks for the help but the link you suggested is based on perl scripting and need installation of perl and a xsh tool as well(which you maintain as mentioned by you). and unfortunately I cant do that in my office computer.

Comment: You will need a tool to handle the XML, xsh or something else.