# Update attribute values using XMLWriter object

Tags: c#, xml

We are using `Xmlwriter` object to create xml and using below code to write an attribute:
`xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("UIVersion", GetWorkflowAssociationUIVersion(wfa, xmlWriter));`

Now after this we execute some lines of code and based on some conditional code our requirement is to change the value of attribute "UIVersion" again. now we cannot use `xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("UIVersion", foldername)` as it will create a new attribute. Any inputs on how can we update the attribute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify XML existing content in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551307/modify-xml-existing-content-in-c-sharp)

Comment: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx): `XmlWriter` *Represents a writer that provides a fast, non-cached, **forward-only** way to generate streams or files that contain XML data.*  Since it's forward-only you can't rewind and rewrite the attribute you previously wrote.  Instead, use one of XML editing APIs suggested in the answer linked by @dnickless.  Or, just don't write the attribute until you know what you want to write.