# adding a new element below specific node in a xml file using LINQ - C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm new in C# and I have tried everything during days and days but I have no answers to solve my problem.

I have a xml doc like this that populate a treeview in a windows form app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
<folder title='Standard Elements'>
  <folder title='Screw' >
    <folder title='Type 1' >
      <record title='DIN EN ISO 4762' />
      <record title='DIN EN ISO 7964' />
      <record title='DIN EN ISO 21269' />
    </folder>
    <folder title='Type 2' >
      <record title='DIN EN ISO 4026' />
      <record title='DIN EN ISO 4027' />
      <record title='DIN EN ISO 4028' />
    </folder>
    <folder title='Type 3' >
      <record title='DIN EN ISO 4014' />
      <record title='DIN EN ISO 4017' />
      <record title='DIN EN ISO 4762' />
      <record title='DIN EN ISO 24015' />
    </folder>
  </folder>
  <folder title='Bearing' >
  </folder>
  <folder title='Pin' >
  </folder>
</folder>
  <folder title='Shaft' >
  </folder>
</root>
```

I have to include a new element below the node with title "Type 2" or other specified node. I'm using Linq in my application but I have no idea to to handle this ensue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement type2 = doc.Descendants("folder").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("title") == "Type 2").FirstOrDefault();

            type2.Add(new XElement("record", new XAttribute("title", "DIN EN ISO 4029")));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worked perfect. Actually I feel stupid now. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XMLDocument` type provided by the framework. Select the node you need, create a new node object and add it as a child to your selected node.

Your question is similar to this: [Modify XML existing content in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551307/modify-xml-existing-content-in-c-sharp)

Comment: If I understood right to use that solution I would have to modify the structure of my XML file that I'm not able to do because I receive the file from other application. I have to find the node with the attribute "Type 2" and add a new node in it.