# How to save .xml file without overwriting the file and the table? c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have a program which is made for editing **.xml files**. **I can edit and save .xml files**, writing into the file is working properly, but **when I edit and save another XML Table, it is overwriting the previous one.**

My code:

```
            DataTable ds = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
            ds.WriteXml(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            saved = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved!", "Saving.");
```

I know why it is happening, the program is saving what is in the dataGridView at the moment of saving.

I have tried: `ds.Merge()`, `TextWriters` various type of `Streams` and `FileModes`

***So how can I save the xml file without overwriting it completely?***

*Example:*

This is the file what I have:

```
    <catalog>
       <book id="bk101">
          <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
          <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>44.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
          <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
          with XML.</description>
       </book>
<catalog>
```

But when I edit the file, using another XML Table it gets overwritten, and it will look like this:

```
<catalog>
  <plant>
    <name>tulip</name>
  </plant>
</catalog>
```

**Thanks for any kind of help!**

*Sorry for bad language.*

Comment: A save is an overwrite. If you want to alter the file, you first have to read it, then alter it then save the whole file. You can't save part of a file, that makes no sense

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify XML existing content in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551307/modify-xml-existing-content-in-c-sharp)

Comment: *You can't save part of a file* - well, you *can*.. but not with WriteXml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how can I save the xml file without overwriting it completely?

That's what WriteXml does. If you want to load an XML file with one book in it (into a dataset with a books table?) and save it with one book and one plant in it then the dataset you save will have to represent the merged changes (it will have to have a books table and a plants table)

The thing I find confusing about your question is that "the program is saving what is in the datagridview" - a datagridview doesn't show a dataset, which is a collection of datatables - it shows a single datatable. Your DGV cannot simultaneously show a book and a plant. You should thus be absolutely sure the dataset contains a book and a plant even though you can only see one of them

Let's take your book XML there, fix the end tag, and load it:

[image]

At this time there is only the book table

Step on another 3 rows of code to where i've added another table, column and row value and there is another datatable in the set:

[image]

Choosing it in the visualizer changes the DGV to show the tulip:

[image]

And now WriteXml will write a merged file:

[image: x]

Comment: Well: yes, I would like to have a. XML file with eg. a 'plant', and a 'book' table in it, but I can't find a way to merge the two tables.

Comment: You don't merge the tables; a book is not a plant. Your dataset has needs multiple tables, one for book and one for plant. See my edit. Note; if you're reading plants out of one xml file and books out of another, you need to transplant (hah) a table from one dataset to another (e.g. `bookDS.Tables.Add(some_datatable)`) but if the datatable already is inside a different dataset it must be removed first; a table can only be in one ds at a time

Comment: Yes, I needed another Table, that is what I wanted, your code looks like exactly what I wanted, I will try it when I will have the time! Thanks, much appriciated!

Comment: Could you, please show me the code of how did you parse the book XML? From the pictures, I don't really understand it.

Comment: It's just that line `ds.ReadXml("c:\temp\a.xml")` - i took the xml out of your question and saved it in  file in that path - the `catalog` becomes the dataset, the `book` becomes the table, the nodes within `book` become the columns names/values/types. It's not C# but that's jsut because I had a VB project open at the time - they're the same language, just remember that VB uses `()` for array access and c# uses `[]` so e.g. `ds.Tables["plant"].Rows.Add("tulip")...`. In case you never noticed, in modern VS methods are in yellow and properties are in white..